# SQL MVC 2 C# Between operator

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to write SQL query  in MVC 2

```
Select column_name From table
 Where column_name 
  between value1 and val
```

Comment: ASP.NET MVC has nothing to do with writing SQL queries. It's a framework allowing you to develop web applications respecting the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SQL : Select x from table where x > value1 and x < val
LINQ : From x in table where x > value1 where x < val select x
```

Answer (score -1):

Like This

we using model class and entity,

> var mymodel = new modelclass();//Call to viewmodel class  from
>   controller  mymodel.list= db.TableName.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM
>   Tablename WHERE Column_Name BETWEEN '"+value1+"' AND
>   '"+value2+"'").Tolist());

Comment: don't copy paste the code from your work. AssetViewModel is totally unrelated to the question and specific to your codebase. change your answer accordingly and format the code also in your answer

Comment: Hi Mr Nouman, Thank you So much for your suggestion, because first time using this(stackoverflow) account.Thanks